# Tracking a bug while running batch job

Tags: debugging

I have 2000 batches to run in a single batch job. One of the batch gives "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error. I want to track this error. How can I track? I have used debug logs but they are pretty much in quantity. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Use try catch for the DML statement. If it fails in any block, compose an email in the catch block and send it to the desired recipient.

Comment: My code is in production now. I am debugging over there. Can't change my code to reflect changes suggested by you.

Comment: @doga, since you're not able to modify your code, are there any subsequent queries that run within your execute method so that you can at least get an idea where the code is failing? With 2000 records in a batch, there is likely to be a lot to sift through in your logs. Sometimes, hits to the database is the only useful way of finding where you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you need to add some additional error handling to your batch job. This error message will be caused by you trying to reference a variable that is null, you would need to defensively code for this.

One thing you can do, is to add the Database.Stateful interface to your batch apex class method declaration, e.g.

```
global class InvoicePosterBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful
```

By adding this, you can maintain some kind of log of what is happening - you have to be careful though not to exceed the heap size. One strategy I sometimes employ for circumventing that is something like this:

```
    if( Limits.getHeapSize()*1.1 >= Limits.getLimitHeapSize() )
    {
        sendEmail();
        failures = new List<String>();
    }
```

Debugging the batch 'chunks' is difficult because not only do you have your chunk log, you then may have up to 2000 iterations of records within that log.

Another thing you could do, is say reduce your batch size to 1 and then you will see which record is failing, you could do that by querying the AsyncApexJob object, e.g.

```
Select Status, NumberOfErrors, ExtendedStatus 
From AsyncApexJob
Where ParentJobId = '707U0000008qTH7'
and NumberOfErrors > 0
```

You can retrieve the 'ParentJobId' from Setup->Monitor->Apex Jobs

Answer (score 2):

If you had debug logging enabled - just query the table that contains them:

```
select Id, Application, DurationMilliseconds, LastModifiedDate, Location, LogLength, LogUserId, Operation, Request, StartTime, Status, SystemModstamp 
from ApexLog
where status = 'Attempt to de-reference a null object'
```

(of course fine-tune the query to your user, time criteria etc as you see fit)

Then you can view the log by visiting link like that:
https://cs7.salesforce.com/p/setup/layout/ApexDebugLogDetailEdit/d?setupid=ApexDebugLogs&apex_log_id=07LM0000008VWd3MAG

(again - provide your own SF instance and log_id)

---

**EDIT** (to answer the comment)

Yeah, I'm positive Status-based search can be the way to dig it out.

```
select Count(Id), Status
from ApexLog
group by status
order by Count(Id) DESC
```

[image: results from my prod. org.]

Comment: When I am writing the query it return no records. I believe status can only be success or error?

Comment: Well just experiment with the query. I've picked something that really returns rows for me (but it was VF & controller error, not from batch so maybe in batches you get different error message). Change the WHERE clause to `LogUserId = 'your id' AND StartTime >= TODAY` (or whatever is appropriate)? Or initially remove WHERE completely, check the results, sort by Status... I strongly believe it'll work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Log all the error messages in a custom object .This is the best method i have heard so far.Keep the batch Id and record Id that failed and the error message in the custom object for each batch run.You can clean this for every month to avoid huge data in this .